# How you would interpret php assignment statement?

Tags: php

I found an example php assignment statement online which maybe resembles a tertary conditional condensed statement, but not quite.  Does anyone have insight as to how to read this assignment statement?

```
$access = $access || $note->uid == $user->uid && user_access('note resource view own notes');
```

My first guess was "assign to access whatever is in access, or if empty, whether uid values are equal and'd with the return of user_access."  But I get the feeling that is not correct, as it seems illogical.

Comment: Please clarify the reason(s) for the downvote.  The question was clear and I did several searches to no avail before posting.  I noticed that some small grammatical edits were made - thank you.

Comment: I'll upvote you because I agree; there's nothing wrong with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First have a look at the [Operator Precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

`==` comes before `&&` comes before `||` comes before `=`

Thus your statement is more clear with adding the following parentheses:

```
$access = (
    $access 
    || 
    ( 
        ($note->uid == $user->uid) 
        &&
        user_access('note') 
    ) 
);
```

> assign to access whatever is in access, or if empty,

Not quite: assign to `$access` the value `true`* when `$access` already [evaluates to `true`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) (`true`, `1`, `"some string"` etc), or

> whether uid values are equal and'd with the return of user_access

Correct

And otherwise assign `false`. After this statement `$access` is always either `true` or `false`, even when `$access === 'yes'` before.

Note*: `||` and `&&` are boolean operators, only capable of 'returning' `true` or `false`

Comment: Very good clarity.  Thanks for the insight.  Hadn't thought about analyzing operator precedence.

Answer (score 1):

I had this exact type of statement in a library way back, and it's basically an elaborate (or maybe just badly-styled?) null-check. Because PHP uses short circuit evaluation, the right-hand side of the or-expression will not evaluate if the left hand one was null.